# Which projects are on the list of JAVA EE Module Dependancy

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to include a project within another project as EE Dependency in Eclipse.

For some reason, the project I want to include is not displayed in the list of possible projects. 
How does Eclipse decide which projects to use there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WTP 1.5 (Eclipse 3.2+) introduced support for J2EE module dependencies for plain Java projects, external JARs, JARs in the workspace etc](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/1.5/newandnoteworthy/j2ee.html). This is controlled at the level of the Enterprise Application, rather than at the level of an EJB project or a Web Project.

Therefore, if you have a plain Java Project that you cannot add as a dependency to an EJB project, you can have this resolved by creating an Enterprise Application Project containing the EJB, and then adding the Java Project as a Java EE module dependency to the Enterprise Application. Once this is done, the Java Project is available as a Java EE module dependency for the EJB project.